# Browser update to a file without a web server

Tags: web, browser

I need to create a  browser based user interface to update an XML file. Is it possible to do this without a full blown web server?

I read about the PHP in-built web-server but wasn't clear whether it will suit my requirement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, using simpleXML, php. Very easy and clear.
All that you need is already well documented.
See:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_xml.asp
```